# Using NetBeans on ARM Linux?

Tags: debian, java, arm

Is it possible to run NetBeans on a ARM CPU with Linux as OS (maybe Debian) ?

I want to be clear I don't need to compile for ARM (I will use NetBeans only for PHP coding).

So the question is about **Java** and **ARM** and **Debian**.

**Background idea:**
I was just thinking to use a cell phone as my first PC (now that they have 4 cores and 2Gb RAM)

**Update**
A fast  research on Google  confirmed me that JRE is avariable for ARM.
So because Java is a kind of interpreted language there should be any problem (except performance :) in order to run NetBeans on ARM.

Am I right ?

Comment: Ah? you have a usb keyboard connected to your phone to do the development?

Comment: no I'm using touchscreen :P 
This is a just an idea:I mean I don't have such power full phone now, however i guess it not difficult to connect a usb keyboard to a phone through its mini usb

Comment: Oh, can't imagine how slow it would be to use a touch screen ;-P

Comment: not at all if you use the right accessory: http://www.idownloadblog.com/2012/08/22/turns-ipad-into-typewriter/

Comment: Hmm, that's was cool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [`netbeans`](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/netbeans) package in wheezy (Debian testing, soon¹ to become stable), for all architectures. Some of Debian's architectures lack a JDK, but [OpenJDK](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/openjdk-7-jdk) is available on ARM, and I think all the other dependencies of Netbeans as well. So

```
apt-get install netbeans
```

¹  <sub>for Debian values of soon</sub>

Comment: I guess NetBeans doesn't have any dependencies expect JDK and JRE.
There should be any problem installing Oracle JDK for ARM and Official NetBeans for Linux. Right ?